# Libgdx | Creating font in Thread causes black un-textured fonts

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When I try to load fonts via FreeTypeFontGenerator in the a libgdx thread, the font ends up being just black (When not loaded in thread, it is just fine). I will post an image below. How can I get around this? I want them to load asynconiously with my assetManager, but I cant load fonts with assetManager because they must be dynamically created. Thanks! Let me know if there is code that you want to see.

[image]

Comment: FreeTypeFontGenerator doesn't support this. Might be nice for someone to update it to split out the non-GL stuff into a separate method, so it can be done in two stages, the first asynchronous, the second syncrhonous on the GL thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of OpenGL which is foundation on top of which libgdx is built.

In OpenGL, assets have to be loaded (and released) within the current [rendering context](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Context). To load resources (assets or fonts) in a different threads, you need to explicitly make the context current.

See [OpenGL and multithreading](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading)

> **Can I create and dispose of resources in a different thread than the one the OpenGL context is in?**
>
> If you make the context current (wglMakeCurrent for Windows). However, it does not buy you much, if anything at all, so it's not worth the trouble.
>
> It is recommended that you call wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL) if GL context is current on another thread, then call wglMakeCurrent(dc, glrc) in the other thread.

**Example**

Thread_1:

```
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
WaitForThread2(); OrDoSomeCPUJob();
wglMakeCurrent(dc, glrc);
```

Thread_2:

```
wglMakeCurrent(dc, glrc);
DoSome_GL_Work();
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
TerminateThread2_And_GiveControlToThread1();
```

---

The purpose of `AssetManager` is to load asynchronously while safely handling aforementioned OpenGL context switch. So, instead of loading them in a manually created thread, using `AssetManager` is a much safer and better way.

If you have to use manual thread, you'll also have to write manual switch mentioned above. If it is not done, the loaded resources are not available for rendering as they may not be transferred to gpu memory properly (hence black).